# HTML toggle switch state

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a 2 part question

Part 1: in the below html file I have a toggle switch that would like to save the state of so when I return to the page it's position is how I left it

UPDATE:
Page 2 is now holding its saved state
Page2.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>page 2</title>
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: red;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
<script> 
function save(){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('stus');
    localStorage.setItem('stus', checkbox.checked);
}

function load(){    
    var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stus'));
    document.getElementById("stus").checked = checked;
}

function del(){
    location.reload();
    localStorage.clear()

}

load();
</script>
  <body onload="load()"> <input type="button" id="ReserveerButton1" value="save" onclick="save()"/> 
  <input type="button" id="Wisbutton1" value="delete" onclick="del()"/> 

<h2>status</h2>

<label class="switch">
 <input type="checkbox" id="stus">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Part 2: now page2.html is holding its saved state is there away I can get the same state on page1.html

Page 1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#stat').load('bw14.html' '#status')
    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
<a href="page2.html" >Page2</a><label>Status: </label><div id="stat"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For static websites, I can only think of `HTML5 localStorage` or cookies to keep track of and remember information. Have you looked into either of those as tools for this?

Comment: `localStorage` would be answer for both the questions..

Comment: Have now got localStorage working can anyone assist with part 2?

Answer (score 0):

To keep a record of checkbox state you'll have to look into cookies or local storage.

To get the state of your checkbox use:

```
$('.switch input').is(":checked")
```